# MPAndroidChart - How to display text to the left of LimitLine?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm trying to display text on the left of the LimitLine like this:

[image]

However these are the only options I'm getting for setting the position of the `Label` for limit line.

[image]

I'm using `LimitLine.LimitLabelPosition.LEFT_TOP` and it only displays the `Label` above the Limit line.

[image]

```
YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
LimitLine minimumLimit = new LimitLine(50f, "Minimum Limit");
minimumLimit.setLineWidth(0.5f);
minimumLimit.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white_60_opacity));
minimumLimit.setLabelPosition(LimitLine.LimitLabelPosition.LEFT_TOP);
leftAxis.addLimitLine(minimumLimit);
```

How do I display the `LimitLine`'s Label to the left of the `LimitLine`?

**Edit:**

I have also tried used the methods `.setXOffset(50f)` and `.setYOffset(50f)` but this only shifts the position of the label and not the line `minimumLimit`.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like it's possible at the moment, but if you're comfortable modifying the library you could fork it and update the [limit line renderer](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/5a732b04278a983d32856c75ad552f2dcbbd922d/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/renderer/YAxisRenderer.java#L260) - or put in a feature request on the MPAndroidChart github page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a custom `YAxisRenderer` with a little modification of the override method `public void renderLimitLines(Canvas c)`.

The modifications needed for this purpose are:

**1**.To calculate the label width of each limit line to be able to move the limit line to the correct x position like below:

```
limitLinePath.moveTo(mViewPortHandler.contentLeft()+getLabelTextWidth(l), pts[1]);
```

**2**.To draw the label to the new x,y position something like this:

```
c.drawText(label, mViewPortHandler.contentLeft() + xOffset, pts[1]+l.getYOffset(), mLimitLinePaint);
```

Below is a custom `MyYAxisRenderer` containing the above modifications:

```
public class MyYAxisRenderer extends YAxisRenderer {

    private final Paint textPaint;

    public MyYAxisRenderer(ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler, YAxis yAxis, Transformer trans) {
        super(viewPortHandler, yAxis, trans);
        textPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    }

    @Override
    public void renderLimitLines(Canvas c) {

        List<LimitLine> limitLines = mYAxis.getLimitLines();

        if (limitLines == null || limitLines.size() <= 0)
            return;

        float[] pts = mRenderLimitLinesBuffer;
        pts[0] = 0;
        pts[1] = 0;
        Path limitLinePath = mRenderLimitLines;
        limitLinePath.reset();

        for (int i = 0; i < limitLines.size(); i++) {

            LimitLine l = limitLines.get(i);

            if (!l.isEnabled())
                continue;

            int clipRestoreCount = c.save();
            mLimitLineClippingRect.set(mViewPortHandler.getContentRect());
            mLimitLineClippingRect.inset(0.f, -l.getLineWidth());
            c.clipRect(mLimitLineClippingRect);

            mLimitLinePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mLimitLinePaint.setColor(l.getLineColor());
            mLimitLinePaint.setStrokeWidth(l.getLineWidth());
            mLimitLinePaint.setPathEffect(l.getDashPathEffect());

            pts[1] = l.getLimit();

            mTrans.pointValuesToPixel(pts);

            limitLinePath.moveTo(mViewPortHandler.contentLeft()+getLabelTextWidth(l), pts[1]);
            limitLinePath.lineTo(mViewPortHandler.contentRight(), pts[1]);

            c.drawPath(limitLinePath, mLimitLinePaint);
            limitLinePath.reset();

            String label = l.getLabel();

            // if drawing the limit-value label is enabled
            if (label != null && !label.equals("")) {

                mLimitLinePaint.setStyle(l.getTextStyle());
                mLimitLinePaint.setPathEffect(null);
                mLimitLinePaint.setColor(l.getTextColor());
                mLimitLinePaint.setTypeface(l.getTypeface());
                mLimitLinePaint.setStrokeWidth(0.5f);
                mLimitLinePaint.setTextSize(l.getTextSize());

                final float labelLineHeight = Utils.calcTextHeight(mLimitLinePaint, label);
                float xOffset = getLimitLineXOffset(l);
                float yOffset = l.getLineWidth() + labelLineHeight + l.getYOffset();

                final LimitLine.LimitLabelPosition position = l.getLabelPosition();

                //draw the label on the left in the same y position of the limit line
                mLimitLinePaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
                c.drawText(label,
                        mViewPortHandler.contentLeft() + xOffset,
                        pts[1]+l.getYOffset(), mLimitLinePaint);
            }

            c.restoreToCount(clipRestoreCount);
        }
    }

    private float getLimitLineXOffset(LimitLine l){
        return Utils.convertDpToPixel(4f) + l.getXOffset();
    }

    private float getLabelTextWidth(LimitLine l) {

        String label = l.getLabel();
        if (label != null && !label.equals("")) {

            textPaint.setStyle(l.getTextStyle());
            textPaint.setPathEffect(null);
            textPaint.setColor(l.getTextColor());
            textPaint.setTypeface(l.getTypeface());
            textPaint.setStrokeWidth(0.5f);
            textPaint.setTextSize(l.getTextSize());

            int textWidth = Utils.calcTextWidth(textPaint, label);
            float xOffset = getLimitLineXOffset(l);

            return textWidth + (xOffset*2);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

In the above renderer i have added two helper functions one for the calculation of the label text width `private float getLabelTextWidth(LimitLine l)` for a specific limit line and one to get the x offset of each limit line private `float getLimitLineXOffset(LimitLine l)` which you can modify based on your needs.

And you can use the above Renderer like the below:

```
lineChart.setRendererLeftYAxis(new MyYAxisRenderer(lineChart.getViewPortHandler(), lineChart.getAxisLeft(), lineChart.getTransformer(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT)));
```

**Result:**

[image: limit_lines]

**Note:** This was tested with v3.1.0 ('com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0')

Comment: Just tried it and it works perfectly, thanks!